# UIActivityViewController - share with selectable image gallery like Photos app

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

What I'm trying to achieve: http://www.appcoda.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Airdrop-Overview.jpg

Is there anyway to achieve this feature with UIActivityViewController?

Default view displays cancel button at the bottom and clicking anywhere outside the view closes it.

I would like to select multiple images just like Photos app with cancel button on the top and selectable image gallery just above the share view.

Comment: You actually want to customize UIActivityViewController?  is it ?  and want to add gallery option too in  UIActivityViewController?

Answer (score 0):

If you add more than one image, twitter options won't be show in UIActivityViewController. But you will be able to share it with facebook. Try this

```
self.someText = @"Prueba!";
UIImage *shareImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"];
NSURL *shareUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.alink.com"];
self.dataToShare = @[self.someText,shareImage,shareImage,shareUrl];
self.activityViewController =
[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:self.dataToShare
                                          applicationActivities: nil];
self.activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePrint,UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList];

[self presentViewController:self.activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Sonia, thanks for your help, but I think you misread my question. Imagine Photos app with just airdrop sharing. So you have an image slider on top (click multiple images to share) and uiactivityviewcontroller below it.

Comment: Oh, ok i got it. But i think that's not possible because  UIActivityViewController popover our view... i believe photos app slider can work with the UIActivityViewController just because they can modify how UIActivityViewController works and they can add that slider... I hope be wrong!

Comment: ok. Also, is it possible to check if the recipient 'declined' or 'accepted' the share? I want to NSLog 'sent' if sent and NSLog 'declined' if declined by the user

Comment: You can use the completion handler
self.activityViewController.completionHandler = ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {
            if (completed) {
                NSLog(@"The selected activity was %@", activityType);
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"i canceled!");
            }
        };

Hope it helps! :D

Comment: I have used the same code and completed is always '0' for AirDrop, whether you close the UIActivityViewController after or without sharing. Other services like message, mail gives '0' and '1' as expected.